# XSLT add table header base on hierarchy level

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

here is part of my XML represents the hierarchy of Terms. TopTerm is the outermost parent and ChildTerm is the child, which can have as many children as possible.

```
<TopTerm ID="1" Entity="Term" Name="ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT">
    <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="8" Entity="Term" Name="Auditing">
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="36" Entity="Term" Name="Environmental audit" />
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="46" Entity="Term" Name="Type of audit []" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="11" Entity="Term" Name="Incidents">
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="71" Entity="Term" Name="Bruce Beresford" />
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="35" Entity="Term" Name="Case name" />
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="83" Entity="Term" Name="Jack Lemmon" />
        <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="87" Entity="Term" Name="Mary Pcikford" />
    </ChildTerm>
    <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="16" Entity="Term" Name="Monitoring" />
    <ChildTerm Relationship="narrower" ID="18" Entity="Term" Name="Policies and procedures" />
</TopTerm>
```

I'd like to have an XSLT 1.0 HTML output with table, and the result should look like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Level 1</th>
     <th>Level 2</th>
     <th>Level 3</th>
     <th>Level 4</th>   
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>ENVIRONMENTAL MANAGEMENT</td>
     <td>Auditing</td>
     <td>Environmental audit</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Something like that. My problem is I don't know the depth of this hierarchy to add the appropriate `<th>Level x</th>` where x can be any number base on depth. And the term level should match the table heading.

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you've tried till now?

Comment: I've not tried anything yet because I don't know where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is I don't know the depth of this hierarchy to add the
>   appropriate `<th>Level x</th>` where x can be any number base on
>   depth.

Well, you will just have to grab the one that is the deepest and iterate over its ancestors. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="TopTerm">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ChildTerm[not(*)]" mode="header">
                <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor-or-self::*)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ChildTerm[not(*)]"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ChildTerm" mode="header">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="concat('Level ', position())"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ChildTerm">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice, seems like this is what I'm after. Thank you so much

Comment: @JackLe If your question is answered, don't forget to close it by accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I'm still very new to stackoverflow and don't know the processes :)